# "How to mitigate the risk of team members leaving" looks valid now; can it be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The OP has edited [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/10426/4271). It seems properly phrased as a PM question now; in fact, I'd like to give an answer to it. Can it be taken off-hold now?

Comment: See [the currently open question](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/10434/4271) inspired by the community input from the old question you're asking about. Then see my answer below for why I think the original question should be left closed.

Comment: Fair enough, when I wrote the question above the community question had not been posted (to my knowledge). However I also think the new question, as written, is a specialised case of a more general "How can the PM mitigate against people leaving the project". My sense is that the current question does capture the OP's essence, however the more generic question is also relevant. Don't like the use of jargon "bus factor" in the new question's title- not everyone has heard that term (I hadn't!)...

Comment: @jmort253 Is this question an appropriate post for tagging with [tag:status-declined], which currently has no wiki definition, or is that tag reserved for other purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Technically, yes. However, for a number of reasons outlined below, I'd like to see this particular question remain closed, and the heavily edited question the OP inspired the community to create should be moved to a new question.

### Reasons Not to Re-Open

The OP didn't actually edit [the question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/10426/4271), but you can see how the community [modified the question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/posts/10426/revisions) to make it fit. In fact, I edited it myself just this morning.

A question can be re-opened by flagging for moderator attention, or by having enough re-open votes. However, in this case, there are some interesting meta-questions that (in my mind) argue against re-opening it:

1. While this is now a good question, has it been edited so much that it no longer resembles the original question?

   To me, it seems like it is now a completely different question. That's not really what editing is supposed to be for.
2. If the question is no longer the original question, should the OP receive upvotes (or downvotes, I suppose) for a question that isn't really the one originally asked?

   From my point of view, while an *improved* question makes the Internet a better place, a *different* question ought to be asked as a different question. I would recommend someone who cares enough about the new, on-topic question ask it as a separate question and gain some rep. The old question can eventually be linked or deleted.
3. What should we do about invalidated or obsolete answers to the original question?

   One person already [answered the old question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/10427/4271). If we re-open the question, the answer may attract downvotes or become obsolete if it no longer directly addresses the newly-edited question. While this is always a risk with editing, we shouldn't set out to deliberately obsolesce a well-intentioned answer.

Comment: So if we left this question closed, would it make more sense to rollback the edits to the original version and then copy the latest edit to a new question?  Also, another option, one that helps avoid duplicated and similar content, is this: *Ask the op to edit further, and also maybe see if [IndikaM](http://pm.stackexchange.com/users/7620/indikam) is okay with making edits to the answer posted.*

Comment: @jmort253 The question is on-hold; if the OP abandons it and it is closed, then it should probably just be deleted. I don't see the point of a roll-back by anyone but the OP because that just leaves a broken window. He still has time to edit the original question if he wants to make it more on-topic, but different than the related one it inspired.